# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in orderby check function

Tags: php

I have this function for check sortby (DESC or ASC):

```
function is_check_sortby($sortby,$default){

    $array = array( 'DESC', 'ASC' ); //line 92

if (in_array($array,$sortby)) {
     $sort = $sortby;
      }
       else
        { 
            $sort = $default;
         }  
      return $sort;   
}
```

For check:

```
$sortby = is_check_sortby($_GET['order'],'DESC');
```

But in action i see this error:

```
 <b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/class/functions.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
```

how do fix this problem ?!

Comment: What part of the warning isn't specific enough?

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and check the argument order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

Check `in_array` usage in http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
 function is_check_sortby($sortby,$default){

        $array = array( 'DESC', 'ASC' ); //line 92

    if (in_array($sortby,$array)) {
         $sort = $sortby;
          }
           else
            { 
                $sort = $default;
             }  
          return $sort;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of arguments of in_array(). It should be:

```
if (in_array($sortby,$array)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in_array should be

```
in_array($sortby,$array)
```